# How do i install socket.io c++ client library

Tags: c++, cmake, socket.io

I am trying to use socket.io c++ client implementation.I have never used an external library before with c++ so im confused.

This is the library i am trying to use:

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp

So i followed this instructions:
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp/blob/master/INSTALL.md

Installed boost and cmake as its stated and i guess it is fine.
My problem is with the 4th step and the rest of it.

If i run

```
make install
```

console throws:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

current dir looks like:

[image]

To be honest i didnt understand what is 5th step, and the installation process in general.How should i include this library in my main.cpp so that i can use it ? What are those visual studio project files generated ?

Edit:
If i open INSTALL visual studio project file and build INSTALL project from solution explorer,i get this error:
[image]

Edit2:
After updating websocketpp library now i get this error after build:
[image]

Comment: Build the INSTALL target in Visual Studio.

Comment: ***Add <your boost install folder>/lib to library search path*** That means you edit your linker settings to add the path of the library. `Linker->General->Additional Library Directories` is the setting for library search paths in Visual Studio.

Comment: If i right click to INSTALL from solution explorer and then click Build, i get this : https://i.imgur.com/tLxy5J5.png

Comment: "_I have never used an external library before with c++_" - My thoughts are with you, seriously. _Someone_ should build an external dependency directory for C++ libs/software to hook into to make this a non-issue.

Comment: The listed errors have nothing at all to do with step 5 of the instructions.

Comment: I think this bug in the software is the cause: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp/issues/212

Comment: now the problem is how do i update damn websocktpp library :D

Comment: I think `git submodule update` in the `websocktpp` folder if you have `git` in your path when running from a `cmd.exe` window.

Comment: There is a cmake file in the directory and no make file

Comment: After updating websocktpp old error is gone i updated my question with the new error

Comment: Some of the new errors are probably due to a different version of boost than this software expects,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are having lots of issues this is how i solved mine:

boost 1.7.0 was not working for me.I installed boost 1.65.0

after that update websocketpp library
go to `C:\socket.io-client-cpp\.git\modules\lib\websocketpp`  directory with command line and type

```
git pull origin master
```

so after changing boost version to 1.65.0 and  updating websocketpp finally it built succesfully.

Comment: You can also use boost 1.72 for instance if you update the websocketpp sources using the command you provided. (I think you still have an error and need to remove two semicolons from the sources) However, at the time I am writing this, the master branch is just the devel branch merged, so expect a lot of logs in the terminal which might interfere with your logs.